# Why HDFS is write once and read multiple times?

Tags: hdfs

I am a new learner of Hadoop.

While reading about Apache HDFS I learned that HDFS is write once file system. Some other distributions ( Cloudera) provides append feature. It will be good to know rational behind this design decision. In my humble opinion, this design creates lots of limitations on Hadoop and make it suitable for limited set of problems( problems similar to log analytic).

Experts comment will help me to understand HDFS in better manner.

Answer (score 7):

HDFS follows the write-once, read-many approach for its files and applications. It assumes that a file in HDFS once written will not be modified, though it can be access ‘n’ number of times (though future versions of Hadoop may support this feature too)! At present, in HDFS strictly has one writer at any time. This assumption enables high throughput data access and also simplifies data coherency issues. A web crawler or a MapReduce application is best suited for HDFS.

As HDFS works on the principle of ‘Write Once, Read Many‘, the feature of streaming data access is extremely important in HDFS. As HDFS is designed more for batch processing rather than interactive use by users. The emphasis is on high throughput of data access rather than low latency of data access. HDFS focuses not so much on storing the data but how to retrieve it at the fastest possible speed, especially while analyzing logs. In HDFS, reading the complete data is more important than the time taken to fetch a single record from the data. HDFS overlooks a few POSIX requirements in order to implement streaming data access.

http://www.edureka.co/blog/introduction-to-apache-hadoop-hdfs/

Answer (score 7):

There are three major reasons that HDFS has the design it has,

- HDFS was designed by slavishly copying the design of Google's GFS, which was intended to support batch computations only
- HDFS was not originally intended for anything but batch computation
- Design a real distributed file system that can support high performance batch operations as well as real-time file modifications is difficult and was beyond the budget and experience level of the original implementors of HDFS.

There is no inherent reason that Hadoop couldn't have been built as a fully read/write file system. MapR FS is proof of that. But implementing such a thing was far outside of the scope and capabilities of the original Hadoop project and the architectural decisions in the original design of HDFS essentially preclude changing this limitation. A key factor is the presence of the NameNode since HDFS requires that all meta-data operations such as file creation, deletion or file length extensions round-trip through the NameNode. MapR FS avoids this by completely eliminating the NameNode and distributing meta-data throughout the cluster.

Over time, not having a real mutable file system has become more and more annoying as the workload for Hadoop-related systems such as Spark and Flink have moved more and more toward operational, near real-time or real-time operation. The responses to this problem have included

- MapR FS. As mentioned ... MapR implemented a fully functional high performance re-implementation of HDFS that includes POSIX functionality as well as noSQL table and streaming API's. This system has been in performance for years at some of the largest big data systems around.
- Kudu. Cloudera essentially gave up on implementing viable mutation on top of HDFS and has announced Kudu with no timeline for general availability. Kudu implements table-like structures rather than fully general mutable files.
- Apache Nifi and the commercial version HDF. Hortonworks also has largely given up on HDFS and announced their strategy as forking applications into batch (supported by HDFS) and streaming (supported by HDF) silos.
- Isilon. EMC implemented the HDFS wire protocol as part of their Isilon product line. This allows Hadoop clusters to have two storage silos, one for large-scale, high-performance, cost-effective batch based on HDFS and one for medium-scale mutable file access via Isilon.
- other. There are a number of essentially defunct efforts to remedy the write-once nature of HDFS. These include KFS (Kosmix File System) and others. None of these have significant adoption.

Answer (score 3):

An advantage of this technique is that you don't have to bother with synchronization. Since you write once, your reader are guaranteed that the data will not be manipulated while they read.

Answer (score 1):

Though this design decision does impose restrictions, HDFS was built keeping in mind efficient streaming data access.
Quoting from **Hadoop - The Definitive Guide**:

> HDFS is built around the idea that the most efficient data processing pattern is a
>   write-once, read-many-times pattern. A dataset is typically generated or copied
>   from source, and then various analyses are performed on that dataset over time.
>   Each analysis will involve a large proportion, if not all, of the dataset, so the time
>   to read the whole dataset is more important than the latency in reading the first
>   record.