# Simulate WORM media

Tags: linux, mount-point

I need to develop archiving software for WORM media.

This type of media permit the usual access acctions : read, write, but once a file is written, it can't be modified or deleted.

Because such media could be expensive, I would like to know how can I create a fake WORM mount point for tests during development phase.

I am using linux, is there something that can permit me to acheive this?

Comment: Hum, no great answer on this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/548765/write-once-read-many-worm-using-linux-file-system, or Gluster (http://staged-gluster-docs.readthedocs.io/en/release3.7.0beta1/Features/worm/) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675312/why-hdfs-is-write-once-and-read-multiple-times.  Couple options...

Comment: Great ! Thanks @Nic3500, it wasn't easy, as I had to create 2 VM with glusterfs, but after that, with a CIFS share, I have my worm mount point. If you want to create a reply, I will gladly vote for it.

Comment: Great I could help, I built a glusterfs cluster a while ago, it's not super easy the first time around for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

- you could use Gluster (http://staged-gluster-docs.readthedocs.io/en/release3.7.0beta1/Features/worm/)
- HDFS mentionned in this thread here on SO: [Why HDFS is write once and read multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675312/why-hdfs-is-write-once-and-read-multiple-times)
- Or OpenAFS (https://serverfault.com/questions/548765/write-once-read-many-worm-using-linux-file-system)

Comment: Used GlusterFS which is way simpler than HDFS to deploy. Accessed with CIFS share. Works great. Thanks.