# Conceptual understanding of hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I just can not understand why in hadoop file system, files in hdfs can only write-once and have strictly one writer at any time. 
Does this rule mean I can not update the file after I write it? And why can not there are two writers at the same time. Is it beacuse hdfs should make file sequentially writes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675312/why-hdfs-is-write-once-and-read-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that you can't modify your files. The philosophy of **hdfs** architecutre is **write once, read many times** and because of **block data** architecure and **replication** architecture,  hdfs use one writer.